# Does TensorFlow have functions like caffe convolutional layer "group" param?

Tags: tensorflow, caffe

There is a parameter named "group" in caffe convolutional layer.
I want to use this "grouping" feature in TensorFlow, how should i do it?

Comment: You might want to add an explanation of the function of the group param so tensorflow people who don't have experience in caffe can answer (like me!)

Comment: explained here : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3332

Comment: sorry, copied from official caffe comments. \n  group (g) [default 1]: If g > 1, we restrict the connectivity of each filter to a subset of the input. Specifically, the input and output channels are separated into g groups, and the iith output group channels will be only connected to the iith input group channels.